# How to return an array of at least 4D: efficient method to simulate numpy.atleast_4d

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, numpy

numpy provides three handy routines to turn an array into at least a 1D, 2D, or 3D array, e.g. through [numpy.atleast_3d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_3d.html#numpy.atleast_3d)

I need the equivalent for one more dimension: `atleast_4d`. I can think of various ways using nested if statements but I was wondering whether there is a more efficient and faster method of returning the array in question. In you answer, I would be interested to see an estimate (O(n)) of the speed of execution if you can.

Comment: Where should the 4th dimension go when it is added? As another trailing dimension, or as another leading dimension?

Comment: @talonmies Trailing is preferred

Comment: The execution speed is O(1) whatever the method, not O(n).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`np.array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) method has an optional `ndmin` keyword argument that:

> Specifies the minimum number of dimensions that the resulting array
>   should have. Ones will be pre-pended to the shape as needed to meet
>   this requirement.

If you also set `copy=False` you should get close to what you are after.

---

As a do-it-yourself alternative, if you want extra dimensions trailing rather than leading:

```
arr.shape += (1,) * (4 - arr.ndim)
```

Comment: Your do-it-yourself approach is pretty. It took me a while to decode though. For the record: ```(1,) * (4 - arr.ndim)``` creates a tuple of ones. The tuple is either empty if ```arr.ndim``` is larger than 4 or of the appropriate length. Those dimension just get tagged on to the array. Beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

Why couldn't it just be something as simple as this:

```
import numpy as np
def atleast_4d(x):
    if x.ndim < 4:
        y = np.expand_dims(np.atleast_3d(x), axis=3)
    else:
        y = x

    return y
```

ie. if the number of dimensions is less than four, call `atleast_3d` and append an extra dimension on the end, otherwise just return the array unchanged.

Comment: Just to clarify: `expand_dims` -> `np.expand_dims`

Comment: Also, needs a colon on the else; `else` => `else:`.