# Reshaping 1D image array to 4D for Keras

Tags: python, arrays, keras, reshape

I need to pass a 4D array when using keras to build a CNN to compare handwriting. However my image array is only 1D where each entry is a (250,250,3) image.

```
print(x_train[0].shape)
>> (250,250,3)
print(x_train.shape)
>> (543, 1)
```

I get the following error: "expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (543, 1)" (note the size is quite small as I am trying to get a net to work before I build my database).

I have seen several threads with suggest fixe to get my array into the form (n_length, 250,250,3) -- i think. However none of them seem to work for me. I naively tried reshaping my array with

```
x_train.reshape(len(x_train),250,250,3)
```

which will obviously throw an error. If there are any suggestions, they are greatly appreciated.

Comment: At best use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15941428/7919597

Answer (score 0):

`x_train.reshape(len(x_train),250,250,3)` - should definitely work if all of your images have same dimension.

You can try fixing their sizes and remove any corrupted image.

```
import cv2
x_train2 = []
for img in x_train:
    if len(img.shape) == 3:
        x_train2.append(cv2.resize(img, (250,250,3)))

x_train = np.array(x_train2).reshape(len(x_train2),250,250,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is to first create an empty numpy array and copy your x_train data over using a *for* loop.

```
new_x = np.empty((len(x_train),250,250,3))

for i in range(len(x_train)):
    new_x[i] = x_train[i]
```